# Handling scoped_session across multiple modules with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-multiprocessing

I'm newbie using SQLAlchemy and I'm working on a complex ETL process so I did the below simplified code:

**module1.py**

```
class Foo:
    def foo_method(self):
        # doing stuff with database
```

**module2.py**

```
class Bar:
    def bar_method(self):
        # doing stuff with database
```

**main_script.py**

```
from module1 import Foo
from module2 import Bar

def run():
    with Pool(processes = num_workers) as pool:
        responses = [pool.apply_async(some_func, (param)) for param in params]
        for response in responses:
            response.get()


def some_func(param):
    engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    session = Session()    
    # Start doing some stuff with database
    foo = Foo()
    foo.foo_method()

    bar = Bar()
    bar.bar_method()
```

So I have a Pool with worker process. When I call `main_script.run()` each worker creates a database session inside `some_func`. My question is how can I use the same session for each worker in module1 and module2 without passing the session by param to each method? Should I add the follow lines in each module/file?

```
    engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    session = Session()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scoped_session` should be created at the module level. For your project structure, that probably means having a separate module to house the engine and session:

**db.py**

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

**module1.py**

```
from db import Session

class Foo:
    def foo_method(self):
        session = Session()
        session.query(...)...
```

Comment: Hello @univerio, thanks for your ansewer. I will try it but do you have a better approach to suggests me? I will really apreciate it

Comment: @Overflow012 Not sure what you're asking. This is the standard approach. Does this not work for you?

Comment: How would I be able to run my unit tests (with an in memory database) with this approach?

Comment: @Ali They're no different. You just need to conditionally construct a different engine if you're in the test environment.